# Incorrect number of suggested edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

This does not affect the site usage, but could be a slight back-end improvement.

On occasion, after evaluating suggested edits as a 10K user, my title bar shows -1 suggested edits "remaining":

[image]